# Ruby .each but need to add in a unique class for each of them

Tags: ruby

i have the following piece of code that loops through and shows the results however i want to be able to set a class for each of the `<td>` and unsure how to do this as i dont know ruby and doing the frontend on a ruby project.

```
<% priority[1].each do|val|%>
    <td><%=val[1] %></td>
<% end %>
```

It just shows 4 of them so if i can set defined classes great but if not something like class1, class2, class3, class4 would be fine i guess.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<% priority[1].each_with_index do |val,i| %>
    <td class="class<%= i %>"><%= val[1] %></td>
<% end %>
```

Which will give every element a unique class of 'class1','class2' etc for all i.

Marginally more complicated, but this example allows you assign your own class names:

```
<% arr = ['Hi','Hello','Howdy','Yo'] #class names %>
<% priority[1].each_with_index do |val,i| %>
    <td class="<%= arr[i] %>"><%= val[1] %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Be sure to pick the answer as the correct one if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: i will when it lets me :) 29 seconds left until i can do so.

Comment: haha oh no bother, its not a big deal. I added in the thing about custom class names.

Comment: Thanks for updating, will make classes nicer :)

Comment: The second case would be even nicer with `zip` and argument array decomposition: `<% priority[1].zip(arr) do |(_val),cls| %>` `<td class="<%= cls %>"><%= val %></td>`